# DateTime Array interval

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

I want to create a DateTime Array wich counts 998 steps down from DateTime.now
in 15 minute intervals

wich should like the following

Assuming the time is 20:00

```
{DateTime.now; 19:45; 19:30; 19:15;...}
```

I've never worked with Arrays directly so i am seeking out for help here

Comment: DateTime.AddMinutes(-15);

Comment: Why? What purpose does this serve?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials and examples out there on how to work with arrays and the same for working with `DateTime`. You can ask a specific question here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use LINQ for this, in combination with `DateTime.AddMinutes`. LINQ makes it very easy to generate a sequence, and then convert that sequence into an array:

```
// Important: only call DateTime.Now once, so that all the values are
// consistent.
// Note that this will be the system local time - in many, many cases
// it's better to use UtcNow.
var now = DateTime.Now;
var times = Enumerable.Range(0, 998)
                      .Select(index => now.AddMinutes(index * -15))
                      .ToArray();
```

A non-LINQ approach would first create an array of the right size, and populate it:

```
// Same comments about DateTime.Now apply
var now = DateTime.Now;
var times = new DateTime[998];
for (int i = 0; i < times.Length; i++)
{
    times[i] = now.AddMinutes(i * -15);
}
```

I definitely prefer the LINQ version..

Comment: Sorry, overlooked index variable.

Comment: i forgot to mention that this array will be inserted into a graph, and it seems like this array fu**s the graph up

Comment: @SebastianWaffenschmidt: Well without knowing more than "it doesn't work" (expressed less politely) we can't really help. I've provided the answer to what you were asking - that's all anyone can do, really.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just checked, your code works perfectly fine, Thank you! It is a chart issue